# Prevent local web application from copy

Tags: web-application

Is there any way to prevent a local web application from being copied to another computer? I searched all over the web and whereas desktop applications have been replaced at a big extend by web application, i haven't find a way to prevent my application from being copied at least without a special effort. Is there any way to achieve this? Something like combine it with a specific mac or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the HTML, css, and JavaScript have been downloaded to a browser, it's out there.

If your code is so amazing that you don't want anyone else even looking at it, you could send the entire page as an image, then every user interaction could send a separate http request and have your server render a new image back after each interaction. This would be a massive headache. It would probably have horrible performance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. For sure it will be a big overhead. My code is not so amazing, but how can i prevent the from copying the www folder from his local computer and install it to another one?

Comment: You could obfuscate it so much and include a bunch of execution commands on strings from regexes in it that people are fearful that it's malware and decide not to use it at all. They probably won't copy it then...